# Worklight 6.1 deploy to windows phone 8: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, deviceId null

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

Good afternoon everybody,
I am experiencing an error on deploying a mobile app to Windows Phone 8.

- It is a Worklight 6.1.0.1 hybrid application deployed to windows8phone, android and iphone.
- It is an application written with Angularjs.

Build and deploy to WL server is ok, deploy of all adapters is ok. The application runs correctly on iphone and android (devices).
By using WL simulator, the app works correctly with windows 8 phones (we are testing a Nokia Lumia 820 device).

Then, I open the visual studio project (vs express 2013), contained into native folder of the windowsphone8 environment, and try to run on official MS emulator and directly on the device.

After the app starts on the device, I get an error in the WL Server console:

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0059E: Login into realm
>   'WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule' failed. The field "deviceId" of
>   instance "null" contained a null value; the metadata for this field
>   specifies that nulls are illegal.. [project MobileBanking] The field
>   "deviceId" of instance "null" contained a null value; the metadata for
>   this field specifies that nulls are illegal.; nested exception is
>   
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The field
>   "deviceId" of instance "null" contained a null value; the metadata for
>   this field specifies that nulls are illegal. [ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E:
>   Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message:
>   An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule
>   WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule, User Identity Not available.
>   [project MobileBanking] [project MobileBanking]

Further info- Authentication.
I have one realm and one security test:

```
<realms>
   <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="WSAuthRealm">
   <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
    <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.onAuthRequired" />
    <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout" />
   </realm>
</realms>

<securityTests>
    <customSecurityTest name="AuthAdapter-securityTest">
      <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="WSAuthRealm" />
    </customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>
```

We have also tried the following possible solutions:

- Imported the IBM WL official demo project: singleStepAuth and doubleStepAuth. They have been correctly deployed on the devices and work.
- Got the URL from the WL simulator console and opened it directly from the windows explorer of the mobile and it works good.
- Tried to reduce to the minimum all WL calls to the server and deployed to the device but the app still blocks.
- Deleted and regenerated windowsphone8 environment from the WL app in Eclipse, but nothing changed.

Maybe the trouble lies into the native wp8 nutshell or into some environment params configuration.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to the Properties view > Capabilities and verify the ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE is ticked (enabled). See if it helps.

Comment: Thank you Idan, but it's still not working. I tried to tick ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE and it didn't work, same thing when I ticked ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER. The error is the same. Any other idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we solved.
It was an angularjs problem about $routeProvider -> templateUrl.
Not a WL problem though it seemed.

When working with windowsphone8 the root of the Partials Url must be **www**, that is:

For Android and Iphone the correct path for partials html is

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : "partials/login.html",
        controller : "LoginController"
    });
...
```

Whilst for WindowsPhone8 the path must be absolute

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : "www/default/partials/login.html",
        controller : "LoginController"
    });
...
```

Anyway, the error message still remain. But everything works fine.